PowerApps collection limiting at 100 rows
I have a use case where my user will need to bulk update large numbers of records. I am currently using a collection method to gather their selected items from a gallery, then utilizing a patch function to update the records in my SQL table. The check boxes are individual to the records in the gallery and a "select all" above the gallery.
Select all ck box
ClearCollect(
    colData,
    Review_gal.AllItems);

individual select ck box
Collect(colData,ThisItem);

In my test case data I have 103 records total, the collection when select all is applied only retrieves 100 records. I then pass the collection into my Update/Patch function through a button
UpdateIf(
colData,
true,
{
    ReviewStatus: Status_upd_lbl.Selected.Value,
    Notes: Notes_lbl.Text,
    NexusRequestID: Value(NexusReq_lbl.Text),
    Reviewer: UserFullNm_lbl.Text,
    LastUpdateTimestamp:Now()
}
);
Patch('UAR.CurrentDeltaAudit_TST',colData);

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get all 103 records into the collection and then get them successfully patched.
